# I need to constantly send data from one activity to another in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, bluetooth

In my **MainActivity**  I have the bluetooth connection process happening and I'd like to constantly send the data arriving to another Activity (**UI**), so that it can be properly displayed to the user.

I was able to "sort of" do it in the following manner, but it is not exactly what I'm looking for, since the **UI** activity gets restarted every time I have new data incoming, and therefore the "activity starting" animation happens everytime. This update shouldn't be noticeable for the user. Is there any way I can use Intents to pass the data I need constantly from **MainActivity** to **UI** without restarting **UI** everytime?

How it is working as of now, with the undesirable **UI** restarting:

On the first activity (**MainActivity**):

```
  Intent UIdata = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UI.class);
  UIdata.putExtra("data", finalData);
  startActivity(UIdata);
```

And on the second activity (**UI**):

```
  Bundle dataIn = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (dataIn != null){
    String UIdataIn = dataIn.getString("data");
  }
```

Thanks!

Att Lang

Comment: how are you getting finalData? can you show code snippet also?

Comment: use LocalBroadcastManager for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is logically flawed. An Activity is only "active" while it's in the front. If you need something which send/receives data continuously even when in background you need to user a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

From there you have multiple possibilities to updated the UI of your running activity, for example:

1) The service can [broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) intents and the activity can have a listener which listens to intents

2) You can [bind](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) an activity to a service and then use methods/variables defined in the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventBus
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

example:
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/effective-android-components-communication-with-greenrobot-eventbus--cms-27654